# Qt: Disable a Push Button without turning it gray

Tags: c++, qt

I need to make a checkable Push Button in Qt 4.8 that when is checked it becomes disabled.

The problem that I have is that the button turns gray and I need to keep it with the same color always. I have two questions for two possibles paths to follow:

1) Is there a way to disable the gray out effect when I use button.setEnabled(false)?

2) Is there a way to hook the click event so I can "simulate" the disabled property?

Thanks in advance!

[Edit] To give a little context, I have two push buttons that should toggle each other and that's why I need to prevent clicking on a pressed button.

Comment: Is it OK if the button still visually depresses when 'disabled'?

Comment: Yes, I need that the button looks depressed but colored

Comment: This may be of use if you want to stop mousepressevent from going to the button: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter

Comment: What do you mean by disabled then? What happens when a user try to uncheck?

Comment: The only way that the button should be unchecked is when the user checks the other button... The user shouldn't be able to uncheck it by clicking on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To give a little context, I have two push buttons that should toggle
>   each other and that's why I need to prevent clicking on a pressed
>   button.

You should use [QButtonGroup](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qbuttongroup.html) instead.

> The only way that the button should be unchecked is when the user
>   checks the other button...

[From doc](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qbuttongroup.html#exclusive-prop):

> In an exclusive group, the user cannot uncheck the currently checked
>   button by clicking on it; instead, another button in the group must be
>   clicked to set the new checked button for that group.

Answer (score 3):

Try [button.blockSignals(true)](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qobject.html#blockSignals). You could also overwrite the look of the button when its disabled with a Qt style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

For disabling toolbutton and put icon of your choice instead of turning into grey

1. you have to load icon creating QPixmap object say qpm,
2. create QIcon object say icon
3. `icon.addPixmap(qpm,QIcon::Disabled,QIcon::On)` this line will show icon
4. setIcon on toolbutton
5. setStyleSheet

When enabling Toolbutton just change
3. `icon.addPixmap(qpm,QIcon::Normal,QIcon::On)`